# How do we get the previous props using the useState setter?

Tags: reactjs

In the class components we can have a previousProps in the setter of setState, but how do we get it inside the useState setter ?

Here are 2 examples:

- The Functional Components example is not aware of the changing props and is behind with one step. In order to solve this issue, this example will require an extra render and a useEffect and results in 2 re-renders.
- The Class components works perfectly because has the 'prevProps' and results in a single re-render.

I can't find anything about this one. Thank you :)

**Functional Components**

https://jsfiddle.net/9uankv23/

```
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

    import { useState } from 'react';

    const Counter = ({ step, increment }) => {
        const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

        const clickHandler = () => {
            increment();

            setCount(prevCount => prevCount + step);
        };

        return <button onClick={clickHandler}>{count}</button>;
    };

    const App = () => {
        const [step, setStep] = useState(0);

        const increment = () => {
            setStep(prevStep => prevStep + 1);
        };

        return <Counter step={step} increment={increment} />;
    };

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ran5uvbo/

**Class Components**

```
    import React from 'react';

    class Counter extends React.Component {
        state = {
            count: 0,
        };

        onClick = () => {
            this.props.increment();

            // This mimics the behavior of the counter component in the previous version of the app
            // this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + this.props.step });

            this.setState((state, props) => ({ counter: state.counter + props.step }));
        };

        render() {
            return <button onClick={this.onClick}>{this.state.count}</button>;
        }
    }

    class App extends React.Component {
        state = {
            step: 0,
        };

        increment = () => {
            this.setState(({ step }) => ({
                step: step + 1,
            }));
        };

        render() {
            return <Counter step={this.state.step} increment={this.increment} />;
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: In your example, the variable `const` is your current state before you call `setCount`. So you could see it as `count` is the previous state to the new state you need to have. Does it make any sense to you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't really understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useEffect` hook to set `counter` *after* `step` has changed in the parent component.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Counter = ({ step, increment }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    increment();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(count + step);
  }, [step]);

  return <button onClick={clickHandler}>{count}</button>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);

  const increment = () => {
    setStep(prevStep => prevStep + 1);
  };

  return <Counter step={step} increment={increment} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, really appreciate it. I already mentioned this approach, unfortunately this requires 2 re-renders.

Comment: Ah, I missed that!